# Animaciones en android studio (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación a la cual le estoy creando un SplashScreen simple, con 2 o 3 animaciones. tengo 2 imágenes, la primera se desplaza desde arriba hacia abajo (eso ya lo tengo echo) y la segunda imagen tiene que desplazarse desde la izquierda hasta el centro, permanecer unos segundos allí y luego desplazarse hacia la derecha hasta desaparecer. La parte en la que se desplaza desde la izquierda ya la tengo echa, me faltaría hacer que se desplace hacia la derecha y desaparezca. Adjunto código de mi activity SplashScreen y mas abajo mis animaciones:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView bingo4_imageview, logo_imageview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        //AGREGAR ANIMACIONES
        final Animation animacion1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.desplazamiento_arriba);
        final Animation animacion2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.desplazamiento_izquierda);
        final Animation animacion3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.desplazamiento_derecha);

        bingo4_imageview = findViewById(R.id.bingo4_imageview);
        logo_imageview = findViewById(R.id.logo_imageview);

        bingo4_imageview.setAnimation(animacion1);
        logo_imageview.setAnimation(animacion2);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                logo_imageview.setAnimation(animacion3);
                /*Intent siguiente = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(siguiente);
                finish();*/
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

Desplazamiento arriba:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-50%"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000"/>

</set>
```

Desplazamiento izquierda:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-150%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

Me faltaría hacer el desplazamiento desde el centro hacia la derecha, no se si ponerlo en un handler o como hacerlo... alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la dirección de desplazamiento `X de (-) a (+)`.
Establece el repeatMode y repeatAcount a 0 en el anim carpeta.
Coloca su imagen en el centro en el  activity_main.xml, por ejemplo(android: gravity = "center".
Te dejo el código de la carpeta anim.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="+150%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:repeatMode="0"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.1"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```